# Jest without NPM or YARN?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, installation, jestjs

Is it possible to install Jest for VS Code without a package manager like NPM or YARN?

I am at a loss for what I should do next, I have tried googling around but all answers seem to point to using NPM or YARN. Unfortunately, I can not use a package manager in my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `jest-core` alone has 27 dependencies. How are you going to install and manage them? Do you want to manually download each of these dependencies from the internet in the correct version? And also all the dependencies of each dependency?

Comment: That does sound like a dependencie hell

Comment: Yes, that's the reason dependency managers were invented. The technical answer is: Yes, it's possible, otherwise package managers couldn't handle it. But the practical answer is: No, it's impossible to do this manually.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain _why_ you can't use a package manager - what _is_ your situation?

Comment: @jonrsharpe in a situation where a simple web app that not using npm.Example a Django with template.So javascript were imported from script src tag

Answer (score 1):

No, Jest has many dependencies and a package manager is needed to pull those dependencies and transitive dependencies correctly. That is not something that can be manually done easily.

With that said, what you can probably do is install Jest globally and run it against a file in your project that is not using npm.

Install Jest globally

```
 npm install -g jest
```

Add a basic config file to your project

```
// ./jest.config.js
const config = {
    verbose: true,
  };
  
  module.exports = config;
```

Run your test

```
jest ./test.spec.js
```